# Is it possible to develop an Android app that monitors the use of other apps?

Tags: android

I am a long time lurker on Stack Overflow where generally the solutions I sought already existed on here. However, I am stumped trying to find information on tackling this problem.

Basically, I am looking at making an Android app - first time making such an app - and part of the functionality is to monitor what else the phone user is doing and then maybe create a log of what the person has done. For example, spent 27% of the time when the phone screen is on using Facebook.

As for my actual Android Studio experience, all I have created so far is a simple app that takes in text from an input field and alerts it back out to you. I am studying a video series to learn how to use and develop with Android Studio.

I am enthusiastic about the challenge, so if anyone has some good resources or information to help me achieve this I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to track applications usage, using google API.
Here is [google resource link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html)
What may interest you the most is [the part concerning UsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html)

You can use this since api 5.0. You can then for example use method `getTotalTimeInForeground()` to get the total time this package spent in the foreground, measured in milliseconds, which seems to correspond to your needs.
Therefore, using your Facebook example. After you get the package name (`com.facebook.katana`) , you could get the application (Facebook) uptime on a daily/weekly/monthly base.

Also, you could use `getLastTimeUsed()` and make your application logs those timestamp then do some maths.

Comment: This is a link only answer.  It would be much improved if the gist of the link (or links) was included into the answer itself.

Comment: Just to be clear, I can use this resource to run in my app and it will be able to tell me that Facebook was running 15% of the time? Sorry for being un-informed, I am very new to this stuff and there's a lot of information on the web and it can be overwhelming.

Comment: i edited answer according to your question and comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am just wondering, is there no way to run through running processes automatically and record what is running or is this way the most efficient? For example, for every time my app is running, for every other process also running, monitor each process's usage?

Comment: Many application keep working in background. So one application could be running 24hours a day but user might really use it only 2 hours. With your suggestion, you would get the 'wrong' 24 hours. With my suggestion you would have the 'real' foreground duration.